# Should development questions be put on hold or migrated to SO?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

Despite being off-topic on AE, questions about app development are frequently asked here. I generally flag these as needing migration to SO as opposed to marking them as off-topic, because they should have been asked there in the first place, but I often see questions about app development that have been put on hold instead of migrated.

Should development questions be put on hold or migrated to SO? If they should always be migrated to SO, why is there a reason in the flagging menu to put them on hold?

Comment: As harsh as it is, SE network has this as a general rule: [don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We must not become part in bringing down the quality of the flagship product of SE.

A lot of development/programming questions we receive here  tends either to debug the app without explaining how to recreate the scenario, or simply throws up logcat's output without even preformatting it, or other things that are at odds with SO guidelines. There are *very few* questions  we receive here that are clearly written and well-formatted.

Migrating those *bad/poor* questions to SO (a site which already receives a  lot of poorly written development/programming questions) would only burden the site. What's more? If I would happen to be regular at SO and start seeing such  questions being migrated to SO, then I might end up questioning the judgement of whole community for such act.

I believe we should migrate only  well-written and well-formatted questions. Putting the rest on hold would not only teach those newbies how to ask but would also tell them where not to ask.

This isn't only about development questions. I keep this opinion to app suggestions or recommendations as well. I rarely flag for migration to Software Recommendations. Usually, I vote to close them since the guidelines for Softwarerecs.se is very clear and detailed, and most of the questions we receive here don't meet those guidelines. Migrating them to a beta site is definitely a strict no.

That's just my opinion!

---

It is another matter that our efforts in bringing down the amount of development/programming questions are not up to the mark.

Comment: Related [Why was this question closed as off-topic without being migrated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91411)

Comment: This is completely correct.  Most questions we get are either unformatted code dumps, or absurdly broad/give-me-teh-codez questions.  It's quite rare when something deserves migration.